# How to bypass certificate error in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: windows-10, certificate, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to access an intranet server under HTTPS, whose certificate has been autogenerated. With other browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc.) I have the option to ignore this error and to somehow "go ahead at my own risk".

In Edge I only see a red "Certificate error" message, but I cannot find a way to tell the browser: "don't worry, it's OK, just ignore it and go ahead".

Any suggestion?

Note: OS is Windows 10

Thanks!

Comment: Edge only supports SHA2 authority-signed certificates. Either SHA1 or self-signed certificates will fire alarms. (I'm fighting this issue myself and this is the only possibility that seems left.)

Answer (score 24):

On chromium edge type `thisisunsafe` while considering that it is, indeed, unsafe.

Comment: Did _not_ expect that to do anything, haha  (it did)

Comment: Is this serious? Where should we type `thisisunsafe`? In developer console or address bar?

Comment: @kiranpradeep click somewhere on the page and just type it. There is no feedback before it works

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't work for me for Microsoft Edge Version 96.0.1054.29 (Official build) (64-bit). Maybe since it's browser managed by origanisation. I use a different browser now, so not a problem anymore.

Comment: @kiranpradeep new to this trick, and it worked on Version 101.0.1210.32 (Official build) (x86_64) on macOS, but not on Windows for some reason. There are lots of possible settings to go through. Oh actually, on Windows you can click "Turn off warnings".

Comment: AFAIK this no longer works. Definitely not on Edge.

Comment: This worked in Edge 110.0.1587.69 on Windows 11. Don't copy and paste though. Click in a blank area of the white error page and then type the word blind. When I did it, the browser authentication popup immediately came up after I typed the last letter.

Comment: I think this functionality can be disabled in enterprise organizations if the admin prefers

Comment: I fully expected this to be a "joking" reply, but it works beautifully 

Comment: It worked for me with the latest edge version (March 2023).

Comment: it works, seem like hidden magic command when playing game ↑↑↓↓←←→→ABAB :)

Comment: works on version 113.0.1774.42 (Official build) (64-bit). I'm shocked in both a positive and negative way

Comment: this no longer works as of edge v122

Answer (score 0):

Update - August 10, 2019

In the [recent version of Microsoft Edge](https://www.google.com/search?q=edge%20latest%20version), you can do this. So, if you don't see the bypass option, you might have to update/upgrade Windows 10 to update/upgrade Edge. If a major version of Windows (ex: 1903) are not offered automatically through Check for updates, you can get the updates manually through the Update Assistant.

Link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

In Windows 10 1903, you can bypass the certificate error by clicking the 'Details' and then clicking the 'Go on to the webpage' link. This is not recommended since it can be dangerous.

[image: Edge - Screenshot]

Answer (score -3):

This is what that screen looks like for me... Specifically, this is for an internal (intranet) site that uses a certificate which is signed by a trusted internal CA, but I'm going to the wrong URL (the cert is for `brains.corp.<company>.com`, not just `brains`), which triggers the untrusted certificate error screen.
[image: Screenshot of Edge visiting a site with an untrusted certificate]
Do you just not have the "Continue to this webpage (not recommended)" link? Clicking that lets me through to the "untrusted" web page just fine.